# Check if user input matches any of several words in a variable, and if there is a match, show image

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables, textinput

**PRESENT: WHAT WORKS** 
I have a search page in an application that has a predominantly voice interface and also has a text input search option (to search for images). I first worked out the voice commands and have all the images and that works fine, and now I am adding text configurations. Below is the example of what works now, I tested it using only one word as the variable:

HTML

```
<div id="searchBoxPage"class="videoContainer">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
  </form>
  <img id="button1960s_002" class="hiddenElement" src="animsAll/Anims_002_Button_1960s.gif">

  <video    autoplay loop muted>
<source src="videos/music_saint_etienne_only_love_cropped_370x660.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$( "input" )
      .keyup(function() {
        var value = $( this ).val();
        var sixties = "sixties";
      if (value === sixties) {
        $("#button1960s_002").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
      } 
      })
```

**THE ISSUE: ADDING SEVERAL VARIATIONS OF ONE WORD AND CHECKING IF USER INPUT MATCHES ANY OF THEM** Now I am working with the text  part and just realized that *unlike voice, where it has to match the ONE string or string combination (as per API specs)*, **text can have several options for one word as people sometimes misspell words**. 
I used the code above which worked perfectly to show me that one particular image, but now I want to add several options for the same word, as well as a possible combination of words.

in this case the word is "sixties".
and I created the single variable of

```
var sixties = "sixties";
```

which worked. But now I want to add these two additional options below:

```
var sixties =["sixty", "sixtys", "sixties"];
```

and that did not work with the other code I had. What is the best way to also add these words into an array (?) and if there is a match, among any of them, show the image? I know I am missing the "check if there is a match among these words" option but I can't figure out how to change what I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return true if value is in sixties array:

```
if (value.indexOf(sixties) > -1)) {
    $("#button1960s_002").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery you can use $.inArray to check
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

```
var sixties =["sixty", "sixtys", "sixties"];
if($.inArray(value, sixties) !== false) {
    $("#button1960s_002").show().delay(10000).fadeOut();
}
```